# Mutate in R according to the row index?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, na, dplyr

So i merged two data frames in R :

***1st one :***

| Ministry | Meeting | Perso_or_Public |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ministry A | Meeting 1 | Personnal |
| Ministry A | Meeting 2 | Public |
| Ministry A | Meeting 3 | Public |
| Ministry B | Meeting 1 | Personnal |
| Ministry B | Meeting 2 | Personnal |
| NA | Meeting 2 | Personnal |

***2nd one :***

| Ministry | Meeting | Guest | Minister_Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ministry A | Meeting 1 | Alexander | MAN |
| Ministry A | Meeting 2 | Jane | MAN |
| Ministry A | Meeting 3 | Antonio | MAN |
| Ministry B | Meeting 1 | Jessica | WOMAN |
| Ministry B | Meeting 2 | Camilla | WOMAN |
| NA | Meeting 2 | NA | NA |

***Output :***

```
dfA <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("Ministry","Meeting"), all.x=TRUE)
```

| Ministry | Meeting | Perso_or_Public | Guest | Minister_Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ministry A | Meeting 1 | Personnal | Alexander | NA |
| Ministry A | Meeting 2 | Public | Jane | NA |
| Ministry A | Meeting 3 | Public | Antonio | NA |
| Ministry B | Meeting 1 | Personnal | Jessica | WOMAN |
| Ministry B | Meeting 2 | Personnal | Camilla | WOMAN |
| NA | Meeting 2 | Personnal | NA | NA |

As you can see, there is a problem for the Minister_Gender of "Ministry A", and i really don't understand why as there is no typo or any other problem (i checked everything -> no extra-space etc). I tried the following :

```
dfA <- dfA %>% mutate(Minister_Gender=ifelse(Ministry=='Ministry A', "MAN", Minister_Gender))
#doesn't work 

dfA$Minister_Gender <- dfA$Minister_Gender[1:3] <- "MAN"
#tried to mutate by row index
#writes MAN in all the Minister_Gender column
```

I can't use a mutate command with is.na() as the NA in the Minister_Gender column also concern other ministries.
So I was wondering if any of you know how to mutate according to the rows' numbers, but in a better way than what i tried ; or any other method that can work.

**Update**

```
dfB <- subset(dfA, Ministry=="Ministry A")
#0 obs
dfC <- subset(df1, Ministry=="Ministry A")
#0 obs
```

Comment: Can you please share an example of your data, not just a screenshot/table? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please share `dput(dfA[1:6, ])` and `dput(df1[1:6, ])` (or whatever your input data frame names are).  Despite your checking for extra spaces, a problem along those lines is the only thing that makes sense to me for the result you are seeing.

Comment: I did a dput and indeed, the name displayed in the dataset wasn't the "real" one !

Answer (score 0):

One can use `left_join` from package **dplyr** instead:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", text="
Ministry, Meeting, Perso_or_Public
Ministry A, Meeting 1, Personnal
Ministry A, Meeting 2, Public
Ministry A, Meeting 3, Public
Ministry B, Meeting 1, Personnal
Ministry B, Meeting 2, Personnal
NA, Meeting 2, Personnal")

df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", text="
Ministry, Meeting, Guest, Minister_Gender
Ministry A, Meeting 1, Alexander, MAN
Ministry A, Meeting 2, Jane, MAN
Ministry A, Meeting 3, Antonio, MAN
Ministry B, Meeting 1, Jessica, WOMAN
Ministry B, Meeting 2, Camilla, WOMAN
NA, Meeting 2, NA, NA")

library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by=c("Ministry","Meeting"))

# Ministry    Meeting Perso_or_Public      Guest Minister_Gender
# 1 Ministry A  Meeting 1       Personnal  Alexander             MAN
# 2 Ministry A  Meeting 2          Public       Jane             MAN
# 3 Ministry A  Meeting 3          Public    Antonio             MAN
# 4 Ministry B  Meeting 1       Personnal    Jessica           WOMAN
# 5 Ministry B  Meeting 2       Personnal    Camilla           WOMAN
# 6       <NA>  Meeting 2       Personnal         NA              NA
```

BTW, the result is the same as in `merge(df1, df2, by=c("Ministry","Meeting"), all.x=TRUE)`, so there seems to be problem in your data. Please provide your data in a reproducible way, either as inline text to be read with `read.table` or (even simpler) with `dput`.